# Re-pack xps extraction to zip again

Tags: c#, zip, xps, xpsdocument

I extracted an xps to a folder, edit some images and i want to rezip it in order to keep it openable with the XPS viewer, but there is something wrong!.. either if i dont change anything, i cant rezip it an open it with the XPS viewer.

I am using windows "send to compress folder" and WinZip with "No compression | Super Fast | Enh. Deflate" and ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll. But no Success.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the VSTO power tools for Visual Studio to edit and repack XPS files.  Using any ZIP program won't work because Microsoft does something non-standard in the ZIP headers that causes XPS viewers not to recognize the XPS if you ZIP it yourself.

[VSTO power tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/06/22/open-xml-package-editor-power-tool-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This usually means you've ended up zipping the enclosing folder.

Navigate to the folder containing "[Content Types].xml", press Ctrl+A to select all items, right-click and select Send To Compressed Folder, and rename the resulting .zip to .xps.

Comment: I've done exactly that and nothing! I succed with the DotNetZip library!, but i dont know why the other way fail.